# Regular expression for selecting attributes name only from within certain tags

Tags: html, css, regex

What's the regex which allows me to select all the attribute names from `<form>` and `<input>` tags but not from any other HTML tag?

For example:

```
<!-- all attribute names get selected -->
<input class="something" id="yes" type="text" name="my-field" value="Hello, world!">

<!-- class and id don't get selected because it's a div -->
<div class="something" id="no"></div>


<!-- class gets selected -->
<form class="my-form"></form>
```

I'm only after the attribute names

Comment: [By using a DOM parser](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Also which language/technology are you using?

Comment: Not really an answer: This is really more suited for non-regexps. That is, whatever language you are using probably has something along the lines of DOM that makes this much easier than having complex regexps.  It is very hard, and in most regexp engines actually impossible, to write a regexp for this that does not give false positives (or miss some attributes).

Comment: I'm just after the regex which can do this. You see, I'm creating a color scheme in Sublime Text which can color fields within a form.

Comment: That's the point, regular expressions *cant* reliably parse HTML. This is because HTML is *not* a regular language. There will always be edge-cases, and use-cases, that can't be reliably predicted or accounted for. It's somewhat obligatory, but *very relevant*, to quote [Bobince's *exquisite*](http://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince) ['Do not parse HTML with regex' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/82548) at this point.

Comment: @enchance You missed perh's point. This regex does generally not exist. Every solution will necessarily miss some special cases and/or match some special cases that should not have been matched.

Answer (score 2):

Such a regexp would be very complicated to build. Despite the fact that you [can't match all HTML by regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/82548), it would need a very complicated [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check whether the attribute name which you want to match comes after a opening tag whose name is either "form" or "input". Don't try to build such a regex, you'd go crazy and/or end up with an unreadable, non-maintainable or -undestandable monster.

Instead, use a DOM parser (there will be one for your language) and apply DOM selectors and get the attribute names of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy task to do it with regex and actually it is not a good idea to do it with regex. But it is possible >>

```
input = '...';

var tmp = input, found, params = [];
var re = /(<(?:form|input)\b.*?\s)([\w\-]+)=(['"]).*?\3/gi;
do {
  found = 0;
  tmp = tmp.replace(re, function($0,$1,$2,$3) {
    params.push($2);
    found = 1;
    return $1;
  });
} while (found);
```

Check [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2wUGN/).